# ASP.NET Core MVC : Discord Oauth2 request - The oauth state was missing or invalid

Tags: discord, asp.net-core-mvc

I've been trying for hours now to get my ASP.NET Core MVC application to retrieve data from the discord oauth2 API. I'm quite new to ASP.NET Core so I'm probably doing plenty of things wrong, but after so much time and research, I haven't made any progress - that's why I'm asking here.

This the relevant code from my `program.cs` and my `AccountController.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Discord";
})
.AddCookie()
.AddOAuth("Discord", options =>
{
    options.ClientId = "clientid"; 
    options.ClientSecret = "clientsecret"; 
    options.CallbackPath = "/home"; //should be /discord-client??
    options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize";
    options.TokenEndpoint = "https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token";
    options.Scope.Add("identify");
    options.Scope.Add("guilds");
    options.SaveTokens = true;

    options.Events = new OAuthEvents
    {
        OnCreatingTicket = context =>
        {
            var accessToken = context.AccessToken;
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://discord.com/api/users/@me");
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});
```

`AccountController`:

```
private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

public AccountController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}

public IActionResult Login()
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Login action started.");

    var properties = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = "https://localhost:7156/home",
        };

    _logger.LogInformation("Redirect URI: {RedirectUri}", properties.RedirectUri);

    return Challenge(properties, "Discord");
}

public async Task<IActionResult> DiscordCallback()
{
    _logger.LogInformation("DiscordCallback action started.");

    var authenticateResult = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    if (!authenticateResult.Succeeded)
    {
        _logger.LogError("Authentication failed. Redirecting to Login action.");
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }

    _logger.LogInformation("Authentication succeeded. Redirecting to Home action.");

    return RedirectToAction("Home");
}
```

I have read that the `callbackpath` should be something like `/discord-signup` but when I do that, I get an error

> invalid OAuth2 redirect_uri

When I change it to the redirect path at least takes me to the authorise page from discord, but then when I press authorise, I get another error

> The oauth state was missing or invalid

Any help will be appreciated

(Yes, I'm sure my `clientid`, `clientsecret` and `callbackpath` / `redirecturi` are exactly the same as set in the discord developer portal)

Comment: Based on your description and error message its clearly saying that your callback path is incorrect. Could you please double check that your callback path is same as your portal? It shouldn't be ` options.CallbackPath = "/home";` . Because, it either be `options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/auth/callback");` or `/signin-discord";` but depending on your portal it must be matched with your Discord Developer Portal redirect URI.